# Large qwerty keypad in smart tv sdk

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, ime

I've noticed, that there is large qwerty keypad in some apps(Facebook, Browser), that differs from popup. How do I use it in SDK.

P.S. I have multi-scene app, with ime module included in app.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from Samsung support, that you can use IMEShell_Common object. 
First you include these:
`<script type='text/javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/IME_XT9/ime.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/IME_XT9/inputCommon/ime_input.js'></script>`
in body tag
After you can use shell like this:

```
var imeBox = new IMEShell_Common(); 
document.getElementById('search').focus();
imeBox.onShow();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Samsung this can be achieved by IME. A very well described step by step procedure is mentioned in the below link. It also has a sample app that demonstrate the full functionality:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00049/index.html

Here is the small demostration:

Load the plugin js:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Plugin.js"></script>
> ```

Now load the IME js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/IME_XT9/ime.js"></script>
```

Create instance of the plugin:

> var pluginAPI = new Common.API.Plugin();

Now register you IME key and initialize it for a text field.

> ```
>   pluginAPI.registIMEKey();
>     imeMail = new IMEShell("messageText", Main.imeInitId, this);
>     imeMail.setKeySetFunc('qwerty');
> ```

Now just focus on the input field:

> jQuery("#messageText").focus();

For more details, please check the above mentioned URL.
Happy Coding!